# How to find similar document with new vocabulary

Tags: text-mining, similarities, nltk

I am working on a problem of finding similar documents. I am using a Tf-Idf based vector space model representation of documents and it gives me good results.

However when I encounter a document with new words which is out of the current vector space, it gives an error. For example I have two documents represented as vectors of terms with their weights
    Document A -> (A,B,C)--> ( 0.15,0.4,0.3)
    Document B->(C,D,E)--> (0.12,0.3,0.5)

How to compute similarity in these situations and so on

Is there an implementation in `python` or `nltk` which takes care of incrementally extending the vector space as new documents are entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will almost always find new words in a new document, maybe because there are indeed new words or because typos in the text.
I think your best choice is to pick in your word space the most frequent or significant words in your corpora, and then categorize all the non frequent words with a token (i.e "NON_FREQUENT"). Then in you new text you read do the same.